# 'Cases' option missing in Advanced Search - how to correct?

Tags: civicase, advanced-search

'Cases' are missing in Advanced Search (usually the last search item). The last 2 items I have are 'Mailings' then lastly 'Events'.  I can't see any configuration option that sets this, so am puzzled how to fix. This Civi was installed in 2013, don't know whether that's a factor. It's at 5.19.4 and Drupal. Can anyone help - how can 'Cases' be put back in Advanced Search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you go to CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Display Preferences and see if 'Cases' is ticked in 'Contact Search' option? If not check the box and save the setting.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Fixed! I didn't see that. Make that the answer?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! So quick too!

Comment: so can you mark this as answered so that it can help others in the community?